# Php Preg_Match to get Quoted string in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

need to get the quoted string and unquoted string in a array

Sample Data

```
$string='tennissrchkey1 tennissrchkey2 "tennis srch key 3" "tennis srch key 4" "tennis srch key 5"';
```

Desired Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => tennissrchkey1
    [1] => tennissrchkey2
    [2] => tennis srch key 3
    [3] => tennis srch key 4
    [4] => tennis srch key 5
)
```

So far trying with this but no luck yet

```
if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $m)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($m);   
} else {
   //preg_match returns the number of matches found, 
   //so if here didn't match pattern
}
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: is the order important?

Comment: nope the final array can contain values in any order but its important that it contains data as highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` function to do a global match. `(?|....)` called [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). Alternatives inside a branch reset group share the same capturing groups.

```
$re = '~(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~m';
$str = 'tennissrchkey1 tennissrchkey2 "tennis srch key 3" "tennis srch key 4" "tennis srch key 5"';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jW6zL6/2)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => tennissrchkey1
    [1] => tennissrchkey2
    [2] => tennis srch key 3
    [3] => tennis srch key 4
    [4] => tennis srch key 5
)
```

Comment: We are almost there !!!! only issue is strings that are double quoted comes as quoted too in final array like this "tennis srch key 3"  "tennis srch key 4" how can we remove these quotes too from final array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sString = 'tennissrchkey1 tennissrchkey2 "tennis srch key 3" "tennis srch key 4" "tennis srch key 5"';

    $aTmp = explode( ' "', $sString );
    $iCountPieces = count( $aTmp );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountPieces; ++$i )
    {
        $aFormatted[] = trim( $aTmp[ $i ], '"' );
    }
    var_dump( $aFormatted );
?>
```